# Filter list using another list as a boolean mask in polars

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have a polars dataframe containing two columns where both columns are lists.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a': [[True, False], [False, True]],
    'b': [['name1', 'name2'], ['name3', 'name4']]
})
df
shape: (2, 2)
┌───────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ a             ┆ b                  │
│ ---           ┆ ---                │
│ list[bool]    ┆ list[str]          │
╞═══════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ [true, false] ┆ ["name1", "name2"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ [false, true] ┆ ["name3", "name4"] │
└───────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

I want to filter column `b` using column `a` as a boolean mask. The length of each list in column `a` is always the same as the length of each list in column `b`.

I can think of using an `explode`, then filtering, aggregating, and performing a `join`, but in some cases a join column is not available, and I would rather avoid this method for simplicity.

Are there any other ways to filter a list using another list as a boolean mask? I have tried using `.arr.eval`, but it does not seem to accept operations involving other columns.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the most ideal solution, as we groom the data to have a group for every list exploded to it's elements. Then we groupby again by that groups and apply the filter.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a': [[True, False], [False, True]],
    'b': [['name1', 'name2'], ['name3', 'name4']]
})

(df.with_row_count()
   .explode(["a", "b"])
   .groupby("row_nr")
   .agg([
       pl.col("b").filter(pl.col("a"))
   ])
)
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌────────┬───────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ b         │
│ ---    ┆ ---       │
│ u32    ┆ list[str] │
╞════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1      ┆ ["name4"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 0      ┆ ["name1"] │
└────────┴───────────┘
```

Maybe we can come up with something better in polars. It would be nice if the `arr.eval` could access other columns. TBC!

### Edit 02-06-2022

In `polars-0.13.41` this will not be so expensive as that you might think. Polars knows that the `row_count` is sorted and maintains sorted in the whole query. The explodes are also free for the list columns.

When polars knows a groupby key is sorted, the groupby operation will be ~15x faster.

In the query above you would only pay for:

- exploding the row count
- grouping the sorted key (which is super fast)
- traversing the list (which is something we would need to pay anyway).

To ensure that it runs fast, you can run the query with `POLARS_VERBOSE=1`. This will write the following text to stderr:

```
could fast explode column a
could fast explode column b
keys/aggregates are not partitionable: running default HASH AGGREGATION
groupby keys are sorted; running sorted key fast path
```

Comment: Wonderful answer. I'd really like an arr.eval that can access other columns though.